# What exactly does EXISTS do in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I read that the output of the subquery doesn't matter and only its existence matter. But, when I change the code in the subquery, why is my output changing?
These are the tables:

```
mysql> select * from boats;
+------+-----------+-------+
| bid  | bname     | color |
+------+-----------+-------+
|  101 | Interlake | blue  |
|  102 | Interlake | red   |
|  103 | Clipper   | green |
|  104 | Marine    | red   |
+------+-----------+-------+

mysql> select * from sailors;
+------+---------+--------+------+
| sid  | sname   | rating | age  |
+------+---------+--------+------+
|   22 | Dustin  |      7 |   45 |
|   29 | Brutus  |      1 |   33 |
|   31 | Lubber  |      8 | 55.5 |
|   32 | Andy    |      8 | 25.5 |
|   58 | Rusty   |     10 |   35 |
|   64 | Horatio |      7 |   35 |
|   71 | Zorba   |     10 |   16 |
|   74 | Horatio |      9 |   40 |
|   85 | Art     |      3 | 25.5 |
|   95 | Bob     |      3 | 63.5 |
+------+---------+--------+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from reserves;
+------+------+------------+
| sid  | bid  | day        |
+------+------+------------+
|   22 |  101 | 1998-10-10 |
|   22 |  102 | 1998-10-10 |
|   22 |  103 | 1998-10-08 |
|   22 |  104 | 1998-10-08 |
|   31 |  102 | 1998-11-10 |
|   31 |  103 | 1998-11-06 |
|   31 |  104 | 1998-11-12 |
|   64 |  101 | 1998-09-05 |
|   64 |  102 | 1998-09-08 |
|   74 |  103 | 1998-09-08 |
+------+------+------------+

select sname from sailors s where exists(select * from reserves r where r.bid=103);
    +---------+
    | sname   |
    +---------+
    | Dustin  |
    | Brutus  |
    | Lubber  |
    | Andy    |
    | Rusty   |
    | Horatio |
    | Zorba   |
    | Horatio |
    | Art     |
    | Bob     |
    +---------+
    10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    
    mysql> select sname from sailors s where exists(select * from reserves r where r.bid=103 and r.sid=s.sid);
    +---------+
    | sname   |
    +---------+
    | Dustin  |
    | Lubber  |
    | Horatio |
    +---------+
```

***Also, I am not able to understand what r.sid=s.sid is doing here. All the sid in reserves are already from sailors table. Please someone explain it to me.***

Comment: @JonasMetzler I did. I understood it but can you please check if I got that right. I posted it below.

Comment: First sentence 'If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE' -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

The `EXISTS` is a Boolean Operator which indicates that if there is ANY row in the sub-query you passed to it. When you execute this:

```
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM reserves r WHERE r.bid=103)
```

It will return TRUE after finding the FIRST row which has the condition `bid = 103` in Reserves table. The first part of the query doesn't matter, it does not matter what you `SELECT` in Exists and MySQL engine will ignore it, just the `WHERE` clause is the part which makes the difference, you can use Exists even like this:

```
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM reserves r WHERE r.bid=103)
```

In the query above, nothing depends on the values in main query, nothing depends on Sailors table, and if there is ANY row in the Reserves table with `bid = 103`, then it always will return TRUE.

In the second sub-query with EXISTS, you have a different WHERE clause, and it depend on the value of the fields of the main Query, so it will have different result per each row:

```
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM reserves r WHERE r.bid=103 AND r.sid=s.sid)
```

In the above query, per each row in Sailors table, MySQL uses `sid` value to produce the `WHERE` condition of the sub-query in EXISTS operator, so it will returns `TRUE` for a row in Sailors table if there are ANY rows in Reserves table which has a `bid = 103` and `sid = Sailors.sid`, and it will returns False for those that has not such a record in Reserves table, and finally you will get a different result

Answer (score 0):

I think I got that. Exists is used to check if the subquery is existing for the main query. I didn't give any link for the main query and subquery in the first query.

For every name in sailors, independently, the subquery is existing. Hence, I got all the names. In the second query, I added s.sid=r.sid which links the main query and subquery. It checks if for a sname, if bid=103, and also, if s.sid=r.sid.

Please comment if I got that right.